# SQL Error 1452: Cannot add or update child row

Tags: mysql, sql, reference, key, alter

I'm trying to add a foreign key to an already existing table called OrdersTbl. I added a new column called ApprovedBy like so:

```
ALTER TABLE OrdersTbl ADD ApprovedBy BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

After that, I tried setting it as the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE OrdersTbl
ADD CONSTRAINT ApprovedByEmp FOREIGN KEY (ApprovedBy)
REFERENCES EmployeesTbl(EmployeeID);
```

But I keep getting

> Error 1452: Cannot add or update child row

What am I doing wrong? Should I have set the field `ApprovedBy` as FOREIGN KEY instead?

Comment: `ApprovedBy` cannot be null. And when you refer to another table it must contain values that are in table `employeestbl`. You need to fill the values before referencing or allow nulls.

Comment: Please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa?rq=1 , here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104601/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row?rq=1 ,  and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469099/error-code-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

When defining

```
 ALTER TABLE OrdersTbl ADD ApprovedBy BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

then `ApprovedBy` cannot be `null`. The default value will be set which is `0`.

Then you apply a foreign key to `EmployeesTbl`. That means the DB checks that `ApprovedBy` only contains values that are in `EmployeesTbl`. But that is not the case. The values are `0`.

#### So either allow `null` for `ApprovedBy` and set the values later accordingly or set the correct values before adding the foreign key.

Comment: Thank you :) Its just as I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. It seems that I had to change the values in table OrdersTbl manually. In other words, upon adding the column ApprovedBy, the values set for every entry was of course '0' by default. Since there are no Employees with the ID '0' it failed and sent that error.
After manually changing the values in each entry to '1' (Or any other existing ID in table EmployeesTbl) the problem was fixed.